# How to make a liferay navigation portlet mobile friendly?

Tags: javascript, liferay, liferay-theme, liferay-aui

I have a two-column layout Liferay page where I added a navigation portlet in the left column that basically shows a list of my pages. This works fine for desktop, but it's not user friendly for mobile (see top image). Is there a built-in Liferay feature to make it collapse for mobile (see bottom image)? If not, how can this be achieved?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: Image1 - This is how navigation portlet is displayed now]

[image: Image1 - This is how how it should display for mobile]

Comment: which version of LR are you using..???

Comment: Hi @aston, I'm using Liferay 6.2 EE.